# Theoretical Concentration (in PPM) of CO2 production after 1 minute

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I recently conducted an experiment to determine ideal ratio of baking soda and citric acid that would produce the most amount of CO2 in water. We used 250ml flasks filled with 120ml water. The samples themselves all weighed a total of 6.5 grams contained various ratios of Sodium bicarbonate and Citric Acid.

The mixtures were dropped in the water, and stoppered with a CO2 meter which measured the production over a minute. We recorded the PPM of CO2 in the container after a minute for each sample. Overall, the rank of the results supported the hypthesis. However, I am having trouble determining the theoretical value to determine the accuracy.

For example, a 50:50 ratio of 3.25g Sodium Bicarbonate and 3.25g citric acid was recorded to have 102,946 PPM of CO2 in the container after 1 minute. How should I go about calculating the theoretical PPM of CO2 after a minute?

To recap:

- 250mL container
- 120mL water in the container
- Mixture Dropped in water
- Stoppered with CO2 meter, which measures PPM of CO2 in the air inside
  the container
- PPM recorded after 1 minute

How can I determine the theoretical value?

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.